# Cut off gridline at the end in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

[image: d3]

I'd like to cut off the grid line at the end of the graph. If I remove the padding in xScale, then the end tick "2016"'s "16" will be cut off. 
Which part should I fix, yScale, xScale, or the gridline?

```
                //Define X axis
                xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                           .scale(xScale)
                           .ticks(10)
                           .tickFormat(formatTime);

                //Define Y axis
                yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                           .scale(yScale)
                           .ticks(5);

                //Define Y axis gridlines
                function make_y_gridlines() {
                    return d3.axisLeft(yScale)
                    }

                //Create axes
                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "axis x")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
                        .call(xAxis);

                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "axis y")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
                        .call(yAxis);

                    // add the Y gridlines
                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "grid")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
                        .call(make_y_gridlines()
                            .tickSize(-w)
                            .tickFormat("")
                        )
```

Comment: Could you make the padding less?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example for us to play with it?

Comment: @XavierGuihot https://gist.github.com/yudataguy/aa000cc736c5dc208fbf589fa7810ecb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the x-axis is defined with:

```
.range([padding, w - padding * 2])
```

This means, the graph begins at `1 * padding` from the left of the svg container and ends at `width - 2 * padding` from the left. Which means the width of the graph (as opposed to the width of the svg container) is `width - 3 * padding`.

Thus the actual size of the y grid lines should be `width - 3 * padding`.

In the code, this means that you can just replace the ticksize in the definition of the y gridlines:

```
.tickSize(-w)
```

with:

```
.tickSize(-w + 3*padding)
```

It's `-(w-3*padding)` since the ticks by default are going to the left of the y axis and here we want them to the right.